# Tomcat Http 404 - Resource not found error

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

We deployed our Java application in tomcat 7 server. Service is running. When we access the link it gives us the below error:

### **HTTP Status 404 - /Browse

type Status report
message /Browse

### description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42**

Also we are using getRemoteUser function. We need to know how to implement this function properly in tomcat.

Comment: Can you attach the logs ? We cannot guess everything by ourselves.

Comment: The catalina.out and localhost.log from the CATALINA_HOME/logs folder would be useful.

Comment: @WillKeeling Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70117462/http-status-500-internal-server-not-responding